# A lifting problem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $E\overset{\pi'}{\longrightarrow} B'$ and $E\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} B$ be vector bundles.
For $i=0,1$, let $f_i$ be a fiber-preserving open embeddings of $\pi'$ into $\pi$, with $g_i$ the induced embedding of $B'$ into $B$.
$$\begin{array}{ccc}\quad E'&\overset{f_i}\longrightarrow&E\quad\\\pi'\downarrow &&\downarrow\pi \\\quad B'&\overset{g_i}\longrightarrow&B\quad\end{array}$$
**Question**
Let us assume that $g_0$ and $g_1$ are connected through a smooth path $\{g_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ consisting of embeddings of $B'$ into $B$.
Then under what conditions, at least locally, $\{g_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ can be lifted to a smooth path $\{f_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ consisting of open embeddings of $E'$ into $E$, and so connecting $f_0$ and $f_1$?

**Edit (Supplementary Question)**  What if the open embedding $f_0$ and $f_1$ were vector bundle morphisms?

**Edit (to Jason Starr)**: I was originally thinking only to open embeddings.

Comment: Denoting the rank of $E'$ over $B'$ by $n'$ and the rank of $E$ over $B$ by $n$, then there is a (real) Grassmannian bundle $\text{Grass}(n',E)$ over $B$ with fibers isomorphic to the real Grassmannian $\text{Grass}(n',\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Given a homotopy $\{g_t\}$ of $g_0$ to $g_1$, you are asking whether this lifts to a homotopy of the induced morphisms $\widetilde{f}_i:B'\to \text{Grass}(n',E)$.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the maps $g$ and reformulate the problem as follows: pull back $\pi$ to $B'\times[0,1]$ along $g_t$. The bundle $g_t^\ast\pi$ is extended from $B'$ (I assume that $B'$ is paracompact Hausdorff). Choose a trivialization, then $f_0$ can be extended to a homotopy $F_t$ with $F_0=f_0$. However, $F_1$ is not necessarily $f_1$. Nevertheless, you have reduced the problem to the case where $g_i$ is the identity.

Comment: Now in the case where $g_i$ is the identity, there are some obstructions. In the special case where $E'$ is the trivial line bundle, you are asking whether it is possible to connect two nowhere-vanishing sections of the vector bundle $E$. This is typically a non-trivial problem. (Ok, after rereading I realize that this is a simple special case of Jason Starr's reformulation. Maybe helpful nonetheless.)

Comment: The Grassmannian is not enough, since maps $f_i$ are also given, not only their images.